# Do powerline network adapters create a different subnet?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, powerline-networking

My planned network layout is as follows:

[image: network layout]

I've got a clearos server that acts as a router (and DHCP server), a freenas fileserver in the same rack and a [powerline adapter](http://www.tp-link.com/en/products/details/?categoryid=1658&model=TL-PA511) that connects from the switch to the other devices in my house.

However, will the powerline adapters create a different subnet? Because I want the HTPC, desktop and wireless clients to not only see eachother, but also see the freenas and clearos server.

Will all computers be able to discover eachother with this layout?

Comment: What did you use to make this diagram? I like.

Comment: Photoshop, not really that useful for this actually, but it does the job :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say "create a different subnet" it sounds like you're talking about NAT. As long as the device is not performing NAT, you shouldn't have any issues. It would likely be marked as a router with this functionality. You'll also need to make sure all devices are *on* the same subnet, meaning all are on 192.168.1.x or something similar.

Comment: Yeah, I might be mistaken on the terminology, sorry. If I understand correctly: since 1 powerline adapter can communicate with the 3 others, should I assume it acts like a switch and is transparent to the other computers on the network?

Comment: I would assume that. Perusing the documentation it looks like it would function the way you're hoping. Although someone [recently mentioned](http://superuser.com/questions/599048/extending-wifi-range-what-do-i-need-and-in-what-configuration/599067#599067) a similar device that I would suspect could perform NAT for its wireless clients.

Comment: But if the powerline adapter acts like an access point it'll still be transparent right?

Comment: Maybe. :) It could also have an `isolate wireless` "feature". It really depends on what the manufacturer thought best. I would _hope_ it would be transparent but I would want to look through the documentation first.

Comment: Ok, well at least I know what to look for now. I'll check it out, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Power line adaptors act as an ethernet bridge, forwarding ethernet packets over the wire, then back to ethernet.  A subnet has to do with IP addressing, which is a higher level protocol that the power line adaptors know nothing about.  Your computer can't tell the difference between being plugged into the power line adaptor and being plugged directly into the ethernet switch.  Logically you can replace the power line adaptors with an ethernet hub and have the same network configuration.