# How to improve wifi coverage when my router needs to be in an awkward place?

Tags: signal, wireless-networking, networking

I live in a 1100 sq ft (100m²) apartment. I receive internet via an ethernet cable in a small space inside one of the bedrooms, far from the living room and the master bedroom. The router sits in that space, and we have ethernet cabling to all other rooms from there. One of the slots is used for phone cabling, the other slots have short ethernet cables plugging them to the router, so I have wired LAN to all rooms in the house, except for the same room where the router sits (and, if I need, I can use the free port on the router with a long cable to have cabled network in that room too)

The apartment is laid down more or less like this:

```
                       Garden
+--------+-------+-----|____|---------+
|        |       |                  TV|
|   BR1  |  BR2 o| Kitchen & Dining  ++
|o       |r  +---+                   |
+--+     |_--| L |         Living    |
|WI_     _                         o |
+---------+--|_|-+ H +-------|_|-----+
 Bldng    |      | a |  B _  Master  |
 Stair    | Bath | l |  a |  Bedroom |
          |      | l | th | o        |
          +------+|_|+----+----------+
```

The router sits on the (r) mark, all the (o) marks are ethernet outlets.

Obviously, BR1, BR2, The west bathroom and the kitchen have good wifi signal. Even the Building Stairs, with all the anti-flame doors and thick walls get full signal.

However, signal in the master bedroom is rather poor, and when I'm browsing at night, I usually turn of the wifi of my cell phone, for I get way better latency and speed on the LTE network. Also, I have a Fire TV indicated by (TV). Throughput is good, but latency is terrible and quality is rather bad, always losing its connection.

I would like to fix this, but I don't want to spend a lot of money. I've bought a router that was well reviewed, Buffalo 1600AC for ~$90.

Solutions I've thought of:

1. Plug the ethernet cable I receive internet from into the living room path, and place the router into the living room. This solution would have a electronic device sitting in my living room, which is not desirable. Also, Bedroom 1 would have most probably bad signal, but since it's my daughter room, and she is too young to use wifi by herself, that would not be that big of a problem. But I use the Bedroom 2 as a home office, sometimes, and I would lose the fantastic wifi signal I have there.
2. Buy another router, a cheap one, and place it in the master bedroom, with the same network configurations. That would make signal strong in the master bedroom, and could improve the signal for the Fire TV, but that's not guaranteed, and I don't feel comfortable having a wireless router right next to my head.
3. Buy another router, and place it in the living room ethernet outlet, which would have some of the downsides of (1), but not the bad signal on Bedroom 2.
4. Buy a discrete repeater, and place it in a somewhat hidden power outlet in the living room, across the wall from the master bath. That placement has direct visage to the Fire TV, and is close enough to the Master Bedroom so it will improve its signal, and close enough to the router so it gets its signal. However, this power outlet is behind a console that covers the outlet. So I would need a very thin power plug and an extension, and probably would need to place the repeater inside the console drawer, so it doesn't appear.
5. I could also place the repeater near the ethernet outlet in the living room, but I think the sign it would receive from the router to repeat would be low, so making it useless.

What of these items you thing would be better? Any other ideas?

Comment: So you want a stronger WIFI signal in your bedroom, but you'd rather not have electronics emitting that signal near your bedroom? Good luck!

Comment: [7 Proven Ways to Increase Your Wi-Fi Signal](http://www.tomsguide.com/us/boost-wifi-signal,review-1584.html)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Extending WiFi range - what do I need and in what configuration?](http://superuser.com/questions/599048/extending-wifi-range-what-do-i-need-and-in-what-configuration)

Comment: The question is really similar, but this is more specific. It asks for *location*, not which "magic box" to use. (it mentions sometimes using APs, sometimes using repeaters, but it is mostly a radio question -- and that's why I've asked it first on Electrical Engineering StEx website).

Answer (score 1):

You have the basic options down. The only other option is moving the router to the ethernet outlet in the same room, on the other side, which is the midpoint of the house.

The second AP in the living room would be the best option. You can get ones that plug into the wall power outlet, the size of a small wall wart, so only the cable from the ethernet outlet is needed. Tiny, unseen.

But if you have a Fire TV, and not a Fire Stick, or are calling an Android stick a Fire Stick (Amazon brand name), then you should just connect the ethernet jack instead of wifi. All your issues will go away.

Comment: 1. This other option is infeasible because I use that outlet for telephone cabling (I could put ethernet + phone in a single cable, but it would be limited to 100Mbps, and I would have to buy some kind of hub or do a lot of cable mincing).
2. YES, the tiny AP is the way to go, I bought one and will accept your answer if it works
3. I have a Fire TV Stick (and a Chromecast too). But even if it was a regular Fire TV, there's no ethernet outlet near the TV.